# How do I get song title from ICY stream from React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, metadata

I need to access a stream's ICY metadata (i.e. song title, artiste) in React Native. Using `axios.head` returns `icy-metaint: "16000"`, which means the data exists. How do I get the stream's metadata?

Do I use something like `WebSockets` to retrieve the metadata?

The following code:

```
  function icyMetadata() {
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        "Icy-MetaData": "1",
        "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "Access-Token, Uid"
      }
    }
    axios.head('http://ais-sa1.streamon.fm/7261_64k.mp3', options)
    .then(res => console.log(res.headers))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```

Returns:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: "true"
access-control-allow-headers: "ETag, If-None-Match"
access-control-allow-origin: "*"
access-control-expose-headers: "ETag, If-None-Match"
cache-control: "no-cache"
connection: "close"
content-type: "audio/mpeg"
expires: "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"
icy-br: "48"
icy-description: "Unspecified description"
icy-genre: "various"
icy-metaint: "16000"
icy-name: "105.9 Shine FM"
icy-pub: "1"
icy-url: ""
instance-id: "04bcede1dad351aa4d82e0e201345cb5"
p3p: "CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI""
pragma: "no-cache"
server: "AIS Streaming Server 8.1.3-rc3"
set-cookie: ["AISSessionId=5c47fb3377970f3d_1568458_tQIwO3gZ_MjE…x-Age=6000; Expires=Sun, 10 Feb 2019 10:44:29 GMT"]
x-loudness: "-11.134537"
```

Comment: Hey winfred, this is a online radio/streaming service, they don't provide this kind of information in the first place, so you cannot access it by any way...

Comment: @Ahm The streaming service's staff responded and confirmed metadata is available with the audio stream.